# Get all members of a group - transitive

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a call to graph API that returns to me all members of a group - including the users of nested groups?

- To get all direct members for a group, there is [`GetGroupMembers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#GetGroupMembers)
- To get all groups for a user transitively, I have found [`getMemberGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups)

But I didn't find anything to get a list of all members, including subgroups (as in "if I send an email to group xyz, which users will receive it?").

Is there no such function available or did I overlook something?